# Ruby + how to split pdf into separate pages?

Tags: ruby

I'm using `Docsplit` to split `pdf` into pages using

```
Docsplit.extract_pages("my.pdf").
```

But I want to limit the pages to 4. I tried

```
Docsplit.extract_pages("my.pdf", :pages => 1..4)
```

which is not working..

Can anyone suggest me what to do

Comment: Is `:pages` parameter simply ignored, or there are errors?

Comment: no errors.Its getting ignored..Can u suggest me any other way please

Comment: Can you paste the gem link here?

Comment: documentcloud.github.io/docsplit/ ..this is the documentation page

Answer (score 1):

1. install [pdftk](http://www.pdflabs.com/tools/pdftk-the-pdf-toolkit/pdftk_server-2.00-win-install.zip) in you machine if not already done and set your path accordingly
2. remove the ESCAPEs from the lib/docscript/page_extractor.rb:18 file like so:

   pdftk #{ESCAPE[pdf]} burst output #{ESCAPE[page_path]} 2>&1"

change to :

```
pdftk #{pdf} burst output #{page_path} 2>&1"
```

1. by default, the gem ignores the page range you give and it will create one pdf file per page. If you're happy with this, then the output pages are created in the same folder as your input file.

However, the easiest solution IMHO would be to just use to pdftk binary directly, it's quite straightforward: to extract pages 1-4, you could use this snippet :

```
in_file = 'IN.pdf'
range = 1..4
range_s = range.to_s.gsub('..', '-')
cmd = "pdftk.exe #{in_file} cat #{range_s} output pages#{range_s}.pdf"
res = `cmd`.chomp
```

This works, provided that the pdftk executable is in your PATH